# RouteLocator issue in Api-Gateway

Tags: microservices

I am trying to build a api-gateway for different Microservices.

Api-gateway is running in 8765 port number.

QUESTION-SERVICE is one of the micro service that runs on 8080 port.

So when I request for url : http://localhost:8765/questions/allQuestions

Api-gateway should route it to http://localhost:8081/questions/allQuestions. But that's not happening , instead it is giving below error message :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-03-15T22:20:05.403+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/questions/allQuestions"
}
```

below is the application.properties file :

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=8765
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionLocator=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=TRACE

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=QUESTION-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://QUESTION-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=path=/questions
```

Below is my pom file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ahk</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```